# How to get the most up to date value

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with a date and value , but how to i create a checker to give a value 1 to the most up to date record?

Original

| StartDate | ClientID | Value | UpdatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-10-2022 | 101 | 100 | 01-10-2022 |
| 01-10-2022 | 101 | 200 | 11-10-2022 |
| 01-10-2022 | 101 | 300 | 20-10-2022 |
| 01-10-2022 | 102 | 200 | 11-10-2022 |
| 01-10-2022 | 102 | 300 | 20-10-2022 |

Updated

| StartDate | ClientID | Value | UpdatedDate | outdated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-10-2022 | 101 | 100 | 01-10-2022 | 0 |
| 01-10-2022 | 101 | 200 | 11-10-2022 | 0 |
| 01-10-2022 | 101 | 300 | 20-10-2022 | 1 |
| 01-10-2022 | 102 | 200 | 11-10-2022 | 0 |
| 01-10-2022 | 102 | 300 | 20-10-2022 | 1 |

Answer (score 2):

Using windowed MAX:

```
SELECT *, UpdatedDate = MAX(UpdatedDate) OVER(PARTITION BY ClientId) AS Outdated
FROM tab
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a select statement that will produce the output you're showing - this could be established as a view on top of your data.

If you're looking to maintain the "outdated" indicator as a persistent value in the DB, please advise:

```
select
    *,
    1 as outdated
from
    client_values
where
    (start_date, client_id, update_date) in (
        select
            start_date,
            client_id,
            max(update_date)
        from
            client_values
        group by
            start_date,
            client_id
    )
union
select
    *,
    0 as outdated
from
    client_values
where
    (start_date, client_id, update_date) NOT in (
        select
            start_date,
            client_id,
            max(update_date)
        from
            client_values
        group by
            start_date,
            client_id
    );
```